# Method that returns DataReader -- will it cause resource leaks?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, ado.net, adomd.net

Say I have the following code:

```
private AdomdDataReader ExecuteReader(string query)
{
    var conn = new AdomdConnection(ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = new AdomdCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Foo", "Bar");
    return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

Then in usage, you'd wrap the reader in a `using` statement:

```
using (var reader = ExecuteReader("..."))
  ...
```

This would be in contrast to manually opening a connection and executing a reader each time:

```
using(var conn = new AdomdConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(var cmd = new AdomdCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Foo", "Bar");
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        ...
    }
}
```

So I'm basically just trying to reduce boilerplate for reading many similar queries from a database.  Am I exposing myself to resource leaks by doing so?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `AdomdDataReader` as handling the option `CloseConnection` is deferred to them.